# How cherry-pick from one branch to another branch without checkout on this branch

Tags: git, unix, merge, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have 3 branches. `dev`, `master`, `master_copy`. Now I am on the `master` branch and a need cherry-pick commit from `dev` branch to `master_copy` **WITHOUT** checkout to `master_copy` or `dev`  branch. How I can do this?

I need like this `cherry-pick <hash> dev master_copy`

Comment: `cherry-pick` does not have an option to do that.

Comment: Maybe u know another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *do not* want to checkout something else consider using a worktree for that:

```
git worktree add blah master_copy
cd blah
git cherry-pick some-commit
cd ..
git worktree remove blah
```

It's an overkill but at least will allow you to cherry-pick without moving on the default working tree.